# Copy all sheets from current workbook to new workbook except the first sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro-based workbook where I run multiple processes and all the results are stored in the same XLSM workbook. I need to store all the output sheets i.e all the sheets except the sheet(1) to a new workbook and save it as xlsx ( macro-free file )

I have written a very simple code to copy a specific sheet and rename it to xlsx. However, I need to copy all sheets except first one and save it as a macro-free workbook ( so that no VBA code present in output file )

```
Sub copy()

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Output.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: Not tested, but I think it would be easier to copy the file itself, open it and delete first worksheet.

Comment: Imagine 4 sheets (1, 2, 3, 4): Do you want 2 in file2, 3 in file3 and 4 in file4 or do you want one file with 2, 3, 4? And what do you mean by first sheet? The sheet in first position of the tab bar `Sheets(1)` or the sheet named `Sheets("Sheet1")` note that these can be different sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes all sheets starting from the second sheet to the end and copies them into a new workbook, then finally deletes the 'Sheet1' sheet that excel automatically uses as the first sheet. Personally, I think it's probably much easier to duplicate the current workbook and then just delete the first sheet.

```
Sub copy()

Dim NewWkb As Workbook
Dim xWkb As Workbook
Dim x As Integer

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set xWkb = ThisWorkbook
Set NewWkb = Workbooks.Add

For x = 2 To xWkb.Worksheets.Count
    xWkb.Worksheets(x).copy after:=NewWkb.Worksheets(NewWkb.Worksheets.Count)
Next x

NewWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete

'Plenty of different ways to save a file, here's one way for a Mac
NewWkb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Folder\newfile", FileFormat:= 51

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Edited. Should be good now, unless I've missed something else

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking out for. Thank You!